# Getting the maximum sum of pairs' second elements given weight limitation on the first elements

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, optimization

I'm looking at example interview questions and this popped up.

The question asks for a program that takes in two numbers, L (limit) and C (number of cases to be input). Afterwards, C amount of integer pairs are input, where the pair consists of (weight, value).

Now, the program should give the maximum possible value where the weights add up to being less than or equal to the limit.

For example, if someone input:

(10,4), 
(5,2),
(1,1),
(4,9),
(5,7)

The program should output 17. The first pair states that the weight limit is 10 and that 4 test cases are going to be input. The next four pairs are the test cases and the most ideal combination is comprised of the last three cases because their weights add up to <= ten while the value results in 17, which is the highest possible value given the limit.

I have been trying for a while to solve the problem, but I'm not finding a really efficient solution. So far the approach I've taken is to find all possible weights that add up to being less than or equal to the limit, and then simply seeing all their sums, then choosing the largest. But I feel this is a terribly inefficient solution and that better could probably be achieved using some kind of sorting. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance of the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). The Wikipedia page lists a lot of known algorithm that solve this efficiently. You might want to gather some inspiration from these algorithms.